# Why are spectroscopic properties invariant under transformations?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, symmetry

I am trying to understand this paper on Transformation Optics:

[Transforming the optical landscape](https://www.science.org/doi/full/10.1126/science.1261244) by J. B. Pendry, Yu Luo, and Rongkuo Zhao from Science Vol 348, Issue 6234

It states that it's possible to "apply a transformation that destroys the geometric symmetry but leaves the spectroscopic properties intact" (page 3 of PDF).

Is this true for any geometric transformation?
What is the physical reason and intuitive explanation for this? Also, are there any references that would help me understand the underlying physics behind this?
Any examples of how this invariance can be used would also be very helpful.

I also do not understand Figure 4, where the system Fig. 4a can be transformed into Fig. 4b. If anyone could provide an explanation/useful references, that would be greatly appreciated!